# Regex.IsMatch in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I know this is a very basic question, but I was unable to find an answer. I am trying to use the function validateRegexData in C#. All I am doing is to validate something that's supposed to be alphanumeric. So an example I saw had this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(inputString, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
```

I get only PART of the second parameter: why is there a **"+$"** sign? Believe me, I tried reading the documentation for an hour, and still didn't get why the parameter starts with **"^"** and ends with **"+$".** I saw somewhere that $ indicates that everything up until \n is fair game as validation (meaning inside the first parameter).. but that still doesn't explain the + sign, and I'm not even sure if what I read applies here. Thank you so much in advance.

Not that it makes a difference, but it'll be used in SSIS
Sorry - I had used the wrong name, I meant to say **"Regex.IsMatch"** !!

Comment: This was me on first day of learning regex.

Comment: The "duplicate" isn't really what I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
^                 <= Start of line
 [a-zA-Z0-9]      <= Any character in the range a to z or A to Z or 0 to 9
            +     <= Repeat previous pattern (here: [a-zA-Z0-9]) one or more time
             $    <= End of line
```

If you need more explanations in the future about regexes, you can get it explained on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dA7nT3/1) for example

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why do I need the +? Why does it need to repeat the previous pattern??

Comment: @LearnByReading you don't *need* it. I allow you to have a string of a length from 1 to ∞